# For loop javascript not assigning correct value

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a loop which finds all elements in a class that contain the character 'L' and performing an innerHTML command to each. This loop seems to work fine until I get to actually do i.innerHTML = '', where the i's is the array for L strings. Why can't I do it like this? If I do a console.log(i); inside the if statement I get the correct array.

```
letts = document.getElementsByClassName('span2');
for(i in letts){
        if(i.indexOf('L') !== -1){
                i.innerHTML = '';
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You do it wrong.

`i` in `for .. in` loop refers to object property name. It is better to iterate `NodeList` collections (as arrays) with simple `for` loop as described in below.

```
var letts = document.getElementsByClassName("span2");
for (var i = 0, len = letts.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (letts[i].innerHTML.indexOf("L") > -1) {
        letts[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `i` in for-- in loop refers to the `index` (0 based). You should use

```
for(i in letts){
        if(letts[i].indexOf('L') !== -1){
   ...
```

or

```
for (var i = 0, i < letts.length; i++) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

A `foreach` loop is handy in such situations.

Arrays have a `forEach` method, but `NodeList`s don't, for some reason. You could use one of:

- [`.forEach`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) function of underscore.js
- [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function of JQuery (or pretty much any framework)
- or the `[].forEach.call()` [trick](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2012/08/27/vanilla-js/).